# SELECT NAME FROM ABCD WHERE NAME LIKE "+aero+%"AND ROWNUM <= 10

Tags: sql, oracle

SELECT NAME FROM ABCD WHERE NAME LIKE "+aero+%"AND ROWNUM <= 10

what is the syntax error in this line......SELECT NAME FROM ABCD  this is working

Comment: Are you checking for literal  '+' characters

Comment: instead of `"+aero+%"` change it to `'+aero+%'`. Strings in SQL are single quotes and not double quotes.

Comment: In fact double quotes allow you to specify column names, eg. `create table test ("my column name" NUMBER);`

Answer (score 4):

You need **single** quotes:

```
SELECT NAME FROM ABCD WHERE NAME LIKE '+aero+%' AND ROWNUM <= 10
```

And also a space before AND.

**UPDATE**

It's not clear in your question what exactly you're searching for. You may need one of the following instead:

```
SELECT NAME FROM ABCD WHERE NAME LIKE '"+aero+%"' AND ROWNUM <= 10

SELECT NAME FROM ABCD WHERE NAME LIKE '%"+aero+"%' AND ROWNUM <= 10

SELECT NAME FROM ABCD WHERE NAME LIKE '"%+aero+%"' AND ROWNUM <= 10
```

... or some other variation. But the important thing is that you should surrond literals with single quotes and not double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

```
con.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT name FROM abcd WHERE name LIKE '" + aero + "%' AND ROWNUM <= 10");
```

Will find all strings starting with your variable `aero`.

To get all strings containing the String of your variable `aero` use

```
con.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT name FROM abcd WHERE name LIKE '%" + aero + "%' AND ROWNUM <= 10");
```

---

You need to use single-quotes instead of double-quotes:

```
SELECT name
FROM abcd
WHERE name LIKE '+aero+%'
  AND ROWNUM <= 10;
```

If the double-quotes are in the string you search use `'"+aero+%"'`.

If you only want to search for strings containing `aero`, use `'%aero%'`.

Comment: not working.,.,.
pr = con.prepareStatement("SELECT NAME FROM ABCD WHERE NAME LIKE '+aero+%' AND ROWNUM <= 10");

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes around the literal?

No space between the literal and AND?

Answer (score 0):

> You need to give the  character between the  expression and AND operator  . And give single quotes for 
>   your regular expression

Answer (score 0):

If you called that from some program codes, following is more likely, where `aero` is the variable, and % would be acts as wildcard. When aero is `ab`, it will search for `'ab','abc', 'abcd', .......`

```
"SELECT NAME FROM ABCD WHERE NAME LIKE '"+aero+"%' AND ROWNUM <= 10;"
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me whether your **aero** is a literal string 'aero' or the name of a variable in your program.  If it is a literal then do this:

```
pr = con.prepareStatement
         ("SELECT NAME FROM ABCD WHERE NAME LIKE 'aero%' AND ROWNUM <= 10");
```

If it is a variable then you should use a bind variable.  Not only is the syntax much less confusing, it also prevents SQL injection attacks.  I'm no ASP expert, but the syntax is something like:

```
pr = con.prepareStatement
         ("SELECT NAME FROM ABCD WHERE NAME LIKE ?||'%' AND ROWNUM <= 10");
con.setString(1,aero);
```